# Display my toolbar (Node-Webkit) on mac

Tags: json, macos, webkit, nw.js

I work on Mac, i want to display toolbar for my program but i cant, however i specified in my package.json file to show it with this code :

```
{
      "name": "markdown_editor",
      "main": "./html/index.html",
      "single-instance": false,
      "window": {
        "toolbar": true,
        "show": true,
        "icon": "./img/icon.png"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "marked": "^0.3.3"
      }
    }
```

Do you have a solution for this ?

Comment: What is your nw.js's version? I also have same problem in v0.14.0.  (In v 0.12.3 , the problem is not happened)

Answer (score 3):

toolbar is deprecated in 0.13 and it’s always false. The traditional toolbar will NOT be supported including the reload buttons, location bar and DevTools buttons. As a workaround, you can open / close DevTools with F12 (Windows & Linux) or ⌘+⌥+i (Mac). And use win.reload() and win.reloadDev() to simulate the reload buttons.

source: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Migration/From%200.12%20to%200.13/